# Adding data to Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm trying to add a user to firebase storage from my android app, I created a User class :

```
class User {
    var userId:String = ""
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName :String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var phoneNumber:String = ""
    var email:String = ""
    var password :String = ""
    constructor(fName:String,lName:String,address:String,userId:String,phoneNumber:String,email:String,password:String) {
        this.userId = userId
        this.firstName = fName
        this.lastName = lName
        this.address = address
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        this.email = email
        this.password = password
    }
}
```

then I created the user ,after creating the user successfully, I wanted to save the user in the storage, the code below:

```
authRef!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this) {  task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    val userId = authRef!!.currentUser!!.uid
                    val user:User = User(firstName,lastName,address,userId,phoneNumber,email,password)
                    databaseRef!!.child(userId).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener{
                        if(it.isSuccessful){
                            println("success")
                            Toast.makeText(this,"successs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            println("error")
                        }
  }
```

but the data isn't been saved, any idea what wrong?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What does logcat say? Any errors?

Comment: Is any of those messages displayed? Please responde with @

Comment: no errors are displayed, I'm able to login, and create users in the auth, but I'm not able to add data to the database

Answer (score 0):

Do you cave write permissions ? try to use this code inside your ***Project -> Database -> Rules*** and then paste this code

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules.